# How to change the web URL for each page in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have done application using EXtjs 4. Application contains many view screens like Login page, Dashboard. home etc, for to access project local URL is **file:///E:/MyWeb/Web/index.html** . once i visited this URL i will get first Login page because in viewport i have given xtype of Login view. **whenever i will go different page URL wont be change it will be remains same as file:///E:/MyWeb/Web/index.html**, but i can visit all the pages. some scenario if i am in middle, some problem happens in page when i reload the page it will go again Login page itself      i cant be come in current page. again it will ask login and next i need to go required page. **Can we change URL of the project in each page navigation? . How to achieve this one in ExtJs?**. Graet appreciated. Thank you. My viewport code is below.

Code Here:

```
Ext.define('GulfMark.view.Viewport', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: 'fit',
    defaults: {
        autoScroll: true
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        id: 'mainContainer',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'loginView'

        }]
    }],
    listeners: {

    }
});
```

Comment: check https://github.com/brunotavares/Ext.ux.Router

Answer (score 0):

I did it making (app.js)x3. Each app.js, was charged in his index.html ( index1.html, index2.hmtl and index3.hmtl)

Every app.js, it charged with him controllers and respective view.

It's a very quick explanation, but it's easy to do.